# Convert a Spark Dataset column from a UDT to Array<String>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orientdb, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using the Spark OrientDB connector to retrieve some data that looks like the following:

| character | title |
| --- | --- |
| Tony Stark | ["Iron Man"] |
| James Buchanan Barnes | ["Captain America: The First Avenger","Captain America: The Winter Soldier","Captain America: Civil War","Avengers: Infinity War"] |
| Marcus Bledsoe | ["Captain America: The Winter Soldier"] |

The Dataframe returns this as `[character: string, title: embeddedlist]`. An `EmbeddedList` is a UDT defined [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spark-orientdb/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/orientdb/udts/EmbeddedListType.scala)

I would like to treat the `title` as an `Array<String>` so that I can do the following:

```
    val vertices = df
      .select(explode(concat(array('character), 'title)) as "x")
      .distinct.rdd.map(_.getAs[String](0))
      .zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

I'm not sure how to cast/convert the `EmbeddedList` correctly. Running this as-is results in the error: `cannot resolve 'concat(array(name), out)' due to data type mismatch: input to function concat should have been string, binary or array, but it's [array<string>, array<string>]`

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Edit: The way I'm receiving the data is in this structure:

```
    val df: DataFrame = Seq(
      "Tony Stark" -> EmbeddedList(Array("Iron Man")),
      "James Buchanan Barnes" -> EmbeddedList(Array("Captain America: The First Avenger", "Captain America: The Winter Soldier", "Captain America: Civil War", "Avengers: Infinity War")),
      "Marcus Bledsoe" -> EmbeddedList(Array("Captain America: The Winter Soldier"))
    ).toDF("character", "title")
```

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: I'm using Spark 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by casting the `EmbeddedList` to a string and then splitting on the comma. I have to believe there's a more elegant way to do this but this works for now at least.

```
    val vertices = df
      .withColumn("title", col("title").cast("String"))
      .withColumn("title", split(col("title"), ", "))
      .select(explode(concat(array('character), 'title)) as "x")
      .distinct.rdd.map(_.getAs[String](0))
      .zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```